# how to use handle line feed in sed command

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I'm trying to use the sed command to replace a string in an IFS text file with another string that contains a line feed character (\n).  Everything works fine except the line feed character.  Any idea how I might be able to get the line feed (\n) to work?  Below is what I've tried:

1. The IFS text file name is test.txt.  Below is the content of this file:

```
&1
```

2. I ran the following command in an RPGLE program to replace the &1 with the text of "Line 1 \n Line 2", expecting that the \n will get translated into the carriage return and line-feed characters

```
QSH CMD('sed -e "s?&1? Line 1 \n Line 2 ?g" test.txt > test.out')
```

3. The string replacement works, except the line feed (\n) charater.  The result file, test.out, looks like below.  The \n is being translated to character n:

```
Line 1 n Line 2
```

4. I've also tried below and none of them works:

```
QSH CMD('sed -e "s?&1? Line 1 \\\n Line 2 ?g" test.txt > test.out')
QSH CMD('sed -e "s?&1? Line 1 \\\\n Line 2 ?g" test.txt > test.out')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get sed to work.  I ended up using awk utility to achieve it.  Below is the awk command:

```
QSH CMD('export QIBM_CCSID=1252; awk ''{gsub(/&1/, "Line 1 \r\n Line 2", $0); print}'' test.txt > test.out')
```

Answer (score 0):

worked for me from `call qp2term`:

```
> echo "&1" > input.txt                                    
  echo "&1" > input.txt                                    
> cat input.txt                                            
  cat input.txt                                            
  &1                                                       
> sed -r 's/&1/Line 1 \nLine 2\n/' <input.txt >output.txt  
  sed -r 's/&1/Line 1 \nLine 2\n/' <input.txt >output.txt  
> cat output.txt                                           
  cat output.txt                                           
  Line 1                                                   
  Line 2
```

but, I get same behavior as you from QSH.

```
QSH CMD('sed -C 819  ''s/&1/Line 1 \nLine 2\n/'' <input.txt >output2.txt')

QSH CMD('cat output2.txt') 

Line 1 nLine 2n                      
Press ENTER to end terminal session.
```

my guess is it has to do the the CCSID.  Even with the -C 819 switch, the output file is CCSID 37 - ebcdic.

Comment: I think qsh and qp2term run in two different shell environments. 
 I'm guessing that one support \n in sed and the other does not.  I need to run sed from a RPGLE program via QCMDEXC call.  So, I'm not able to use qp2term.  But I'm able to get it to work using awk. Such a bummer to waste a day for a \n.

Comment: @HockChaiLim - While you can't use [QP2TERM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzalf/rzalfterm.htm), you *can* use [QP2SHELL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzalf/rzalfshell.htm) (or QP2SHELL2, if you want to run in the same activation group). You would use these instead of QCMDEXC. (Well, you *could* use QCMDEXC to issue the call to QP2SHELL, but why add another layer?)

Comment: you can also force which ever shell you want through `QSH CMD('exec /QOpenSys/usr/bin/csh ...')` https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/qp2shell.htm it is under the second usage note.